Is there an instance where only one option is allowed in the yaml header of a quarto documnet?
I am making a quarto webpage using VScode IDE. When I add edit the document the character highlighting gets all messed up. I believe it is interpreting the while document as part of the yaml header but i definitely am not missing a dash in the yaml header.

The weird thing is this quarto file renders perfectly fine with no problems but its a pain to edit it because of the weird highlighting.
I've tried adding different combinations of dashes around the yaml header which actually fixed the text coloring:

but it doesn't render now because it doesn't recognize the yaml header.

The coloring you observe seems to imply that the file is wrongly regarded as .yaml. It would work if the file was regarded as .md.

@HeikoTheißen thanks for the comment. This file is not a .yaml or .md, it is a .qmd (quarto markdown file). If I change the file to a .md it doesn't recognize the code chunks in the file.
